# Linker fails for std::map in header

Tags: c++, mingw, std, ld, stdmap

I am trying to create a simple c++ program using code::blocks and mingw, and I am encountering a linking error of some sort.  When I attempt to build the project, ld returns 1 with no additional details.  I have tried searching online for information about this sort of issue, but I haven't been able to find anything.

I tried moving the definition of `example` from `test.hpp` to `test.cpp`, and that does resolve the linking issue, but it makes it so that I can't access `example` from other files that import `test.hpp`.  I have also tried removing the namespace altogether, but I would like to avoid that for organizational reasons (If this is a totally inappropriate usage of namespaces I'd appreciate knowing).  I am trying to make it so that eventually several parts of my program are able to access and update `example` during runtime.

test.hpp

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

namespace testing{

    std::map<std::string,int> example;

}
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace testing {

    std::map<std::string,int> example;

}
```

Build output

```
=== Build: Debug in SilhouetteEngine (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===
error: ld returned 1 exit status
=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a more comprehensive build log somewhere, where it will say that `testing::example` is defined multiple times.

The solution is simple: Only *declare* the variable in the header file, using the `extern` keyword:

```
// In header file
namespace testing{
    extern std::map<std::string,int> example;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it has been a long time since I last took a course in c++ and I had completely forgotten about `extern`.

Answer (score 0):

Both your header and cpp define your variable `example`. You should declare the variable in your header as `extern`.

[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)